# Why is default ordering on a relationship in Rails 4.1.12 not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, relationship

## Background

- An advert has many advertised vehicles
- An advertised vehicle has a price attribute
- I want to sort the relationship by price ascending by default

## The Problem

```
class Advert < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :advertised_vehicles, -> { order(price: :asc) }
end

v1 = AdvertisedVehicle.create(price: 2000)
v2 = AdvertisedVehicle.create(price: 1000)

a = Advert.create(advertised_vehicles: [v1, v2])

a.advertised_vehicles.map(&:price)
# => [2000, 1000] - fails

a.advertised_vehicles.order(price: :asc).map(&:price)
# => [1000, 2000] - works
```

## What Works

In order to get this to work I've had to resort to overriding `advertised_vehicles`:

```
class Advert < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :advertised_vehicles

  def advertised_vehicles
    super.order(price: :asc)
  end
end
```

## What I've Tried

```
class Advert < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :advertised_vehicles, -> { throw order(price: :asc) }
end
```

- This throws the correct ordered relationship
- When I remove the `throw`, the unordered relationship is returned again

## Versions

- Ruby 1.9.3 p547
- Rails 4.1.12

## Question

How do I get the default ordering syntax for relationships to work?

Comment: Is it the same after you reload the Advert after creating?

Comment: Aha! That works. I didn't think you'd need to do that... but hey - it works! Put a proper answer below and I'll mark yours as accepted! :) Thanks so much!

Comment: I suppose you could also sort [v1, v2] prior to, or as part of, the create as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values are not sorted from the database but from how you passed them to `create`: `[v1, v2]`. After creation association is treated as loaded and when you call it there's no need to reload it from database (with proper order clause).

To get them sorted you can:

- sort them manually before creation
- reload whole Advert object (`a.reload`)
- reload just the association (`a.advertised_vehicles(true).map(&:price)`)

Of course, the first one would be most efficient, but you need to keep your sorting code up to date with default scope of relation. So you have to decide what is more important for you.